# Using React Router withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do you get the routing context, location, params, etc, when using **withRouter()**?

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const SomeComponent = ({location, route, params}) => (
    <h1>The current location is {location.pathname}</h1>
);

const ComposedWithRouter = withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

Can you obtain that info using withRouter or do these things have to be explicitly passed down the component tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, no using `context` anymore. It's all available in the props:

```
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: React.PropTypes.string,
    query: React.PropTypes.shape({
      ...
    })
  }),
  params: React.PropTypes.shape({
    ...
  }),
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}

const ComposedWithRouter = withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

So then lets say in `SomeComponent` you wanted to send the user to a new route, you simply do `this.props.router.push('someRoute')`

Comment: So the only solution is to explicitly pass props to child components? What if you wanted to make and distribute a <BreadCrumbs /> component?

Comment: Well, that depends on how tied in with the router you wanted it to be. If say you only cared about distributing it to people using `react-router`, then instead of actually exporting `BreadCrumbs, you would export `withRouter(BreadCrumbs)` and that way it would always have access to the router/location.

Answer (score 1):

Getting location etc. via withRouter was added in react-router version 2.7. Dan Abramov recommends upgrading to 3.0 to use withRouter. Before 2.7, it only provided a set of functions.