# Reactjs/Redux -- this.props.router undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a login system -- when the user fills in the form - I've created a redux action to "authenticate" the user -- so when this.props.authData.isLogged is true -- I want to invoke the navigate function to bounce the user to the home page. However, this.props.router is undefined? But I've defined the withRouter?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import { render } from 'react-dom'
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

// components
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchAuthentication } from '../../actions/authAction';

import LoginSyncValidationForm from './LoginSyncValidationForm'


// this is a class because it needs state
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    // console.log('this', this)
  }

  submit (data) {
    this.props.fetchAuthentication(data);
  }

  navigate() {
    console.log("navigate", this)
    //this.props.router.push('/home');
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.authData)

    if(this.props.authData.isLogged){
      this.navigate();
    }

    return (
      <div className="Page">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <LoginSyncValidationForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authData: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ fetchAuthentication }, dispatch);
}


const {object} = React.PropTypes
Login.propTypes = {
  router: object
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174814/using-react-router-withrouter

Comment: I tried defining the prop types earlier - it still didn't show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically Navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this out. In React router V4 the API has been changed a lot and `browserHistory.push()` can not be used as before. Now you get access to history object in your props inside the component. Calling the push method on history object will push a new entry onto the history stack.

```
  navigate() {
    this.props.history.push('/home');
  }
```

Comment: Appreciate if you can mark it as the answer, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) component like so:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

...
navigate() {
    return <Redirect to="/home" />
}
```

Comment: what is react-router version?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: for testing purpose in your if statement replace `this.props.authData.isLogged` with `true` and add the `return` keyword to `this.navigate`

Comment: -- yeah that bounced me to home

Comment: -- I think it was the return this.navigate() -- that caused a reaction