# Replace only last path part in URL

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, browser-history

I'm using `react-router-dom` *`v4.3.1`*.

> For example: I have the following URL
>   `http://localhost:3000/url1/url2/url3`

I need to replace only last route in URL: `/url3` → `/mynewroute3`

How to do it with *history*?

Comment: In what manner the change should be? `<Link>`? programmatically?

Comment: programmatically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use history.push

```
someMethod = () => {
  const { history } = this.props;
  history.push(`/url1/url2/url_new`);  // change url3 to "url_new"
}
```

`this.props` should have `history` in it if you were using `withRouter` in the root component.

- [SO: Using React Router withRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39174814/104380)
- [Programmatically navigate with React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)

When doing `history.push(...)` the Router picks up the change and acts on it.

#### Only change the last part of the URL;

```
location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/') + '/newPath'
```

#### Regex:

```
location.pathname.replace(/[^/]*$/, newPath)
```

The above takes the current window location path, cut the part after the last `/` (including) and adds a new string (the new path)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is asked for React Router v4 but I was trying to perform same thing with React v5 and find this answer. For future reference, in React Router v5, I was able to perform this using the following;

```
history.push('./mynewroute3'); // Changes last part 

history.push ('./../mynewroute3'); // /url1/url2/url3 => /url1/mynewroute3
```